# Formula for partial word match and return cell value

Tags: excel, match

A4 = Red robbin
B4 = blue robbin

i would like a formula that looks for word red within the 2 cells and if found it would return value of match.

So B2 where forumla would be, would give answer Red robbin.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use `Search` instead of `Find` function because is not cause sensitive.

`=IF(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH("Red",A4,1),0)>0,IFERROR(SEARCH("Red",B4,1),0)>0),A4&" "&B4,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Red",A4,1),0)>0,A4,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Red",B4,1),0)>0,B4," ")))`

1. If both cells `A4 & B4` have red you will get both strings in `B2`
2. If `A4 or B4` has red you will get only the cell with the red in `B2`
3. If no cell has red you will get nothing in `B2`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is something like this:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("red",LOWER(A4)),0)<>0,A4,IF(IFERROR(FIND("red",LOWER(B4)),0)<>0,B4,"not found"))
```

Unfortunately I cannot think of a way to look for a word in a range. I hope this helps.